# Problem at saving a file in certain route that I entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem when I'm trying to autocreate a file when I introduce a route in an Entry. The thing is if the program asks you where to save it, it saves it perfectly, but I would like that my program firstly saves the file if I indicate a previous route in an Entry and ONLY ask me where I want to save it if I don't entry any specific route (which as I said, does it perfectly)

I'm new at Python and don't know what I'm doing wrong, don't know if the problem is that I'm linking wrongly the route in the code and it can't recognize where I'm asking to save it.
When I'm introducing an ID and a route, it gives this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Desktop';
```

and when I'm ONLY introducing an ID (leaving route empty), it gives this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

and what I want is that when I only introduce an ID, I'd like it to ask me where I want to save this file.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

window = Tk()
window.title("app")

idcheck = StringVar()
route = StringVar()

def function():
    if route: 
        **idchecklist = open(route, "w")**
    else:
        idchecklist = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension=".txt")
    idchecklist.write(idcheck.get()) 
    idchecklist.close()

Label(window, text="ID").grid(padx=10 ,pady=10, row=0, column=0)
Entry(window, textvariable=idcheck).grid(padx=5, row=0, column=1, sticky=E+W)
Label(window, text="Saving route").grid(padx=10 ,pady=10, row=1, column=0)
Entry(window, textvariable=route, width=50).grid(padx=5, row=1, column=1)#, sticky=E+W)
Button(window, text="Generate", command=function).grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=2,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=E+W)

window.mainloop()
```

To finish, is there any way to save the route Entry I introduced just in case that I want to use the program more than once and not having to introduce this entry every time? It would be great.
Thank you so much.

ps. Sorry if I did some writing mistakes.

Comment: can you give an example of what you type in `ID` & `Saving route` please within the application?

Comment: By "route", do you mean folder (as in a file system directory)?

Comment: @98Ed Ye for sure, for example: ID: 12GHJ23F (random), saving route: C:\Users\user1\Desktop.

Comment: @martineau I mean a directory, ie: C:\Users\user1\Desktop. Sorry my bad English, it's not my main language.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `route`, but `route.get()` in your code.
`route` in your case is just a container for a string, a StringVar object, so the if considers it being True. `route.get()`, on the other hand, is a string, which is retrieved from the Entry. So, the final code could look similar to this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

window = Tk()
window.title("app")

idcheck = StringVar()
route = StringVar()

def function():
    if route.get(): 
        idchecklist = open(route.get(), "w")
    else:
        idchecklist = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension=".txt")
    idchecklist.write(idcheck.get()) 
    idchecklist.close()

Label(window, text="ID").grid(padx=10 ,pady=10, row=0, column=0)
Entry(window, textvariable=idcheck).grid(padx=5, row=0, column=1, sticky=E+W)
Label(window, text="Saving route").grid(padx=10 ,pady=10, row=1, column=0)
Entry(window, textvariable=route, width=50).grid(padx=5, row=1, column=1)#, sticky=E+W)
Button(window, text="Generate", command=function).grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=2,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=E+W)

window.mainloop()
```

If I'm getting you correct (see comments), here's even better version:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

#  create window
window = Tk()
window.title("app")

#  create some containers for inputs
idcheck = StringVar()
route = StringVar()

#  create input entrys
Label(window, text="ID").grid(padx=10 ,pady=10, row=0, column=0)
Entry(window, textvariable=idcheck).grid(padx=5, row=0, column=1, sticky=E+W)
Label(window, text="Saving route").grid(padx=10 ,pady=10, row=1, column=0)
Entry(window, textvariable=route, width=50).grid(padx=5, row=1, column=1)#, sticky=E+W)

#  Update function
def function():
    if route.get():  #  if route is not '' then use it else ask for it
        idcheckpath = route.get()
    else:
        idcheckpath = filedialog.askdirectory()
        route.set(idcheckpath)
    #  create and fill the file
    idchecklist = open(idcheckpath+os.sep+idcheck.get()+'.txt', 'w')
    idchecklist.write(idcheck.get())
    idchecklist.close()
    #  generate new id:
    alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    #  get the old id and split it into a number and a string
    old_id = idcheck.get()
    if len(old_id) != 8:
        old_id='000000AA'
    letters = old_id[6:]
    number = int(old_id[:6])
    #  check if the last letter is Z
    if letters[1] == alphabet[-1]:
        if letters[0] == alphabet[-1]:  #  if both letters are Z, update the number
            letters = 'AA'
            number += 1
        else:
            letters = alphabet[1+alphabet.find(letters[0])]+'A'  #  if only the last letter is Z, update both letters
    else:
        letters = letters[0]+alphabet[1+alphabet.find(letters[1])]  #  update the last letter
    idcheck.set(str(number).zfill(6)+letters)  #  save a new id

Button(window, text="Generate", command=function).grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=2,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=E+W)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did you try the code in your PC and it worked? Because this code seems fine but doesn't work in my PC. I get this error when I entry a certain route: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: C:\\Users\\User1\Desktop; I'm the admin and I'm also executing Spyder as admin...what else can I try? Thanks again.

Comment: You can't write a text to a directory. I've tried, and it works PERFECTLY. Just enter a path to a FILE in a 'route' entry

Comment: Do you actually need to create a file with an id as a name? Do you need to create a random-named file with an id inside? `C:\\Users\\User1\Desktop` is a directory, that is why you can't write some text directly into it.

Comment: Ok now I get what you mean, it's working now. Thank you so much. I'll keep investigating to see if I can do it automatically without having to write a name. Btw, is there any way to keep that path just in case I want to save lots of files in that but only change the name of the items??

Comment: Sorry I saw your second comment late. Yes, I would like to create a file with the id put in the entry as a name if it's possible. That would be great.

Comment: So, you'd like to enter a path in an 'route' entry, and then to create a new empty file with the ID as a name in that directory. You'd also like to auto-change the ID after each save. Correct?

Comment: Correct. What I want is to only enter an ID and a path, and when clicking the button 'Generate', to create a new file .txt with that ID inside and as a name of the file, and if I want to keep that path, only change the ID I entry and generate a new file with it's new name and that new ID inside, I hope I explained myself well hahaha, for sure I'll improve my English here. One last thing, I saw your last edit, could you possibly, if you don't mind, add some comments # to explain a little bit about the code? I'm new and I'd like to fully understand what is happening. Thank you so much.

Comment: Not a problem, wait please for ~ 6 hrs.

Comment: What is the ID template?

Comment: Sorry for making you wait for so long. Now It should work as you've described